# Water line noise in adjacent suite when washing clothes

Tags: plumbing, water

The tenants in our suite are complaining about the noise that is generated whenever we wash clothes.

The washer is in the basement in the adjacent house. The water lines are going through the wall shared between the suite and the garage, however. The bedroom is on the shared wall with the garage. The garage and suite are at the same level, a few steps down from main floor.

- Water lines in blue
- Washer in black
- Garage in gray

[image: sketch of garage, washer and water lines]

The water lines look like this:

[image: pic of water lines splitting]

- Down: line to washer
- Up: line to house main/meter
- Right: line to suite

Would simply reworking the plumbing, by not having the washer and the suite on the same line, solve this issue?

**Edit #1**

The water line picture is from within the main house. The line going to the suite is enclosed in the walls which are drywalled, puttied and painted.

Comment: What kind of noise are they complaining about? Running water, or a thump when the water flow starts and stops, or something else? Different problems may call for different solutions.

Comment: The sound is running water.

Comment: The filling of water it takes 2 minutes. The washer running takes hour. It is the washer making more noise than the water flow.

Comment: You may have to rip open the drywall and change how the pipes -- and/or the drywall -- are mounted. I know that isn't what you want to hear.

Comment: Those water pipes look pretty darn small. The fittings that plastic pipe is crimped to are even smaller than the pipe inside diameter. The smaller the pipe/fitting, the faster the water runs through it. The faster water flows, the more noise it makes. So, install larger pipes to reduce noise. Failing that, you could reduce water pressure, because that would also reduce the water velocity.

Comment: But is the "running water" noise when the washer is *filling,* or when it's *draining?*

Comment: @huesmann the noise is when it's filling.

Comment: @keshlam agreed. However, on Saturday mornings (or weekends), our household is up earlier and that's when we do the majority of the multiple washes required for our clothing. I'm not surprised by your suggestion to opening up walls to change how the pipes are routed :)

Comment: @kreemoweet FWIW, whatever pipes were used for the suite, matched what was in the existing house, which was built in 2011/12.

Comment: I wonder if you could minimize the amount of drywall work needed by simply drilling small holes and spray foaming around the pipes to provide some sound insulation.

Answer (score 1):

> Would simply reworking the plumbing, by not having the washer and the suite on the same line, solve this issue?

Yes. Water flowing sound comes from friction in the pipe and especially at fittings. The T and L fittings are notorious. The sound generated in the pipe (at the fitting) travels through the house framing and sheathing and along the pipe itself.

Sound generation can be mitigated by reducing the number of fittings, increasing the pipe diameter, and preventing pipes from traveling through or near the quiet area.

Reroute your plumbing so that the T for the washer/suite split is placed further away from the suite. For instance, run separate lines from main/meter for suite and washer. Avoid L fittings and allow the pipe to bend instead, where space permits. Upgrade to a wider 3/4in from meter to washer. Insulate with rockwool so that noise does not travel from the noisy line  through the air of the wall space to potential sound entry points of the suite. Buy long lengths of pipe (>20ft) to avoid straight fittings for extensions.